# Why does Android R SDK not working in Marshmallow?

Tags: android

I updated my SDK version to latest API level 30 (R), so called Android 11. Now, it is running perfect in Android R emulator, but when I try to run on marshmallow version it gives below exception. I tried to delete all SDK and clean/rebuild project, Invalidate cache/restart.

```
  **Exception:**
    Installation did not succeed.
    The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK
    The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level.
```

It'll only work on Android R. What should I do?

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-R'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lifetrenz.lifetrenz_gcc_doctorapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 'R'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

I want to test App from API 21 to API R

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Lifecycle components
    def life_versions = "2.2.0-beta01"

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$life_versions"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$life_versions"

    //Server API Integration
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.1'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.7.1'

    //For QR Scanner
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0'
}
```

Comment: from the error, it seems that your device is running an android <21 and you've defined your minimum SDK to be 21.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo 6.0.1 is 23 right?

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650173/installation-failed-since-apps-minsdkversion-is-newer-than-devices-api-level

Comment: can you post the list of dependencies? maybe something else is forcing a newer minSdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Developer Preview [website](https://developer.android.com/preview/get):

> Android 11 Developer Preview is available on Google Pixel 4 / 4XL, Pixel 3a / 3a XL, Pixel 3 / 3 XL, and Pixel 2 / 2 XL.

As it stands right now you can only run and test apps that target R on the above physical devices and the latest Android Studio emulators running on R. It seems that when Studio is doing the Gradle build and manifest merging, the build tools automatically change your minSdk to R.

Comment: But the question is, if the device is below, then it should use already installed SDK or show option to install missing SDK.

Comment: @PoojaSingh That behaviour will eventually be allowed before the stable release, but not on developer preview stage. Right now an app that targets R can only run on a device that runs on R

Comment: I understood dear. I'm telling that when I not upgraded, that time it was running below 'R'. Now I upgraded to 'R'. So if the device is Android 'R' then it should run 'R' if device is below that then it should run installed SDK. Because previously below R, even I use any device it is not showing any exception.

Comment: @PoojaSingh I'm not sure I follow you. What do you mean by _upgraded_? Changed gradle to point to android-R, downloaded tools v30? added sdk in android studio for R? Created an emulator running on R? All of the above? What's the problem then? Are you trying to launch an app that doesn't target R on a device that doesn't run on R and getting the above error?

Comment: yes, above all. The situation is, I'm working with both 'R' emulator and 6.0.1 tablet simultaneously. I have to test in both. How is it possible? you tell me!

Comment: @PoojaSingh just make sure that you don't target R, when you want to flash your apk to the emulator running on Marshmallow. instead target Android 10 (Api 29) or even lower depending on your needs.

Comment: But the need is both. If you can see that my app support 21 to 'R'

Comment: every 5 min I have to run on both versions to test something.

Comment: @PoojaSingh You either wait a few months till they're closer to releasing the stable version of R and enable debugging for all devices, or you change your Gradle to cater for the devices you want to use right now. Alternatively, you copy your project and import it separately on android studio. edit the gradle accordingly and run the two projects side by side, whilst making sure to copy paste the changes as you go along

Comment: umm, let's see then